# Unable to install pyinstaller version 3.5 onto wine with python27

Tags: python, linux, pyinstaller, wine, kali-linux

I am new to wine and python in general. I am following a course and while creating a reverse shell in python 2.7 one of the lessons is to turn the .py into an exe. I successfully installed wine and python2.7 but when running the the command

`wine /root/.wine/drive_c/Python27/python.exe -m pip install pyinstaller==3.5`

I get the following error

```
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\root\temp\pip-build-xlszqv\pefile\setup.py", line 86, in <module>
    long_description = "\n".join(_read_doc().split('\n')),
  File "c:\users\root\temp\pip-build-xlszqv\pefile\setup.py", line 30, in _read_doc
    tree = ast.parse(f.read())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 3789
    f'Export directory contains more than 10 repeated entries '
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid
```

I have tried installing other versions of python(most updated one I was able to install was 3.3) but had more complications with those versions.

Comment: I'm sure I saw this exact question about a week ago. Pyinstaller clearly needs a reasonably recent version of Python, but there's clearly some dodgy outdated tutorial out there somewhere telling people to install it on an old version of Python on Kali. You should probably treat that tutorial as useless

Comment: OK - this is the one I was thinking of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68725795/4657412 - not quite the same but very similar cause